# How to POST an image in a JSON request?

Tags: json

This is part of the request that returns the image and the QR code. I will need to import those two into the JSON which is generated in the POST request Wallet.

```
 if (r.body.d.Photo){
              card = {
                  id: r.body.d.id,
                  photo:  btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(r.body.d.Photo))),
                  qr:  btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(r.body.d.QR)))
              };
            }



Wallet: function () {
  console.log("Clicked apple wallet button");
  request.post('http://localhost:62666/api/pass')
    .set('Content-type', 'application/json')

    .send({ 
      id: this.state.results.id,
      Photo: this.state.results.photo,
      Qr: this.state.results.qr
     })
   .then(function(data){
      console.log("success", data);
      console.log("text >>>", data.text);
      // store.set("text.pass", data.text);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log("error", err);
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use btoa() to convert the image into Base64 and decode it on the other side.